# Usage of the preposition "in" in the sentence “I will come back in two minutes”

Tags: prepositions, word-difference, time

Can this sentence be rephrased as "I will come back after two minutes"?

> I will come back in two minutes.

What's the difference between *in* and *after* in this context?

Answer (score 2):

"In two minutes" means in approximately two minutes, possibly more, possibly less, but not that much more or less. "After two minutes" means in at least two minutes, possibly a bit more.

Comment: So that means "I will come back after two minutes" is correct. But in my grammar book, we just can use the preposition "in" here, and I don't know why? I think maybe the native speaker are very rigorous about the time,and they will tell us the exact time.

Comment: Really the only differences are that "in two minutes" sounds more natural and "after two minutes" implies you won't be back in less than two minutes. Otherwise, they're about the same.

Comment: I don't think that's it. After all, we could say “after exactly two minutes” to express a precise interval.

Comment: Logically this is correct. Realistically, if you hear "after two minutes" in general conversation the speaker isn't promising the action might not happen in 1 minute 50 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

*In* is the normal preposition when the reference frame is the current time.

> Stay here and wait for me. I am going out and I will come back in two minutes.

Using *after* isn't really wrong but doesn't feel idiomatic. With *after*, I get the impression that the elapsed interval is important, rather than the moment in time when the action happens.

> I am starting the engine, and I will switch it off after two minutes.

*After* conveys that what determines the switch-off time is that the engine should run for two minutes. Contrast with

> I am starting the engine, and I will switch it off when he comes back, in two minutes.

If the reference frame is not the current time, then *in* cannot be used. The idiomatic way to express a time interval uses the adverb *later*.

> When the bell rings, I will go out, and I will come back two minutes later.

(“I will come back in two minutes” would mean that the speaker will come back two minutes after saying this, irregardless of when the bell rings.)

It is also possible to use *after*, and that feels a bit more idiomatic than when the main clause is in the present tense. As before, *after* emphasizes that it is the elapsed interval that matters.

> When the bell rings, I will go out, and I will come back after two minutes. This should give you time to come to a decision.